# Is there a vectorized way of getting the closest (smaller or equal than) value from a list of unique values for each row?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame with a column that has some integers:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2010, 1963, 2014, 1998, 2004, 2010]})
>>> df
      A
0  2010
1  1963
2  2014
3  1998
4  2004
5  2010
```

and a list of unique years:

```
>>> years = [1964, 1973, 1985, 1993, 2003, 2004, 2011]
```

For each item in the column `A`, I want to get the closest value from `years`. However, this value has to be smaller or equal than the respective item in column `A`.

I could use `min()` with a `lambda` and use `apply()` to get the year for each row. I am wondering if there is any vectorized way of doing this?

I want to end up with a DataFrame like this:

```py
>>> df["B"] = some_func(df["B"], years)
>>> df
      A     B
0  2010  2004
1  1963   NaN  # There is not a smaller or equal value than 1963 in years
2  2014  2011
3  1998  1993
4  2004  2004
5  2010  2004
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('A'),pd.DataFrame({'A':years,'B':years}), on ='A')
Out[133]: 
      A       B
0  1963     NaN
1  1998  1993.0
2  2004  2004.0
3  2010  2004.0
4  2010  2004.0
5  2014  2011.0
```